# In a C++ constructor do I have to allocate space for my instance fields?

Tags: c++, constructor

In a C++ constructor do I have to allocate space for my instance fields (specifically I have two pointers as fields) or does calling "new" automatically allocate this space?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking about. The pointers will be there, but pointing nowhere.

Comment: The space for the pointers will be allocated but you are responsible for allocating what they point to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  Instance fields of your classes are automatically allocated.  If they are pointers, space is allocated for your pointers (4 bytes on 32 bit architectures, 8 bytes on 64 bit architectures).  If you want your pointers to point to objects, you will need to either assign them or create objects for them to point to.